# My HP Pavilion DV6 laptop overheats on ubuntu but not on win7

Tags: overheating

HP Pavilion DV6 1256TX gets hotter while running ubuntu 13.04 than on win 7..
I am kind of new on ubuntu..
I tried many methods mentioned on different forums but none could not get it correct.. :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the command `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup`
2. Run the command `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Make sure you do not see noacpi (set it to acpi or delete it, depending on where it is), pci=noacpi (set it to pci=acpi), or acpi=off (set it to acpi=on)
4. Reboot and see if it helps.

Basically, you set Ubuntu to use acpi to control the hardware, which generally fixes overheating. If your computer does not boot, revert /etc/default/grub to /etc/default/grub.backup.

Comment: 1) I tried the 1st command but could not see anything happening.
2)moved on to the 2nd: "The program 'gksudo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gksu". I executed it.
3) after installing executed the command again. It opened something in a text editor.
4)I dont see any of the texts you mentioned to search for. Does that mean its alright.
going to reboot now.

Comment: i see no difference.. :(